Craft 5 MultiSite Setup different Live Preview Links
I'm currently developing a MultiSite website where each site has its own domain.
TBH, it's my first CraftCMS project. Bear with me if the answer is very obvious.
.env
SITE_ONE_URL=https://site-one.com/
SITE_TWO_URL=https://site-two.com/

config/general.php
'aliases' => [
    '@siteOneUrl' => getenv('SITE_ONE_URL'),
    '@siteTwoUrl' => getenv('SITE_TWO_URL'),
],

I created a page section (model) to fill up content. My goal is to display different live previews based on the site and page I'm editing. Since the live preview links are part of the global page section settings, I can only add links for all sites simultaneously as a dropdown.
My Questions:

Is there a better way to dynamically set an alias or variable in general.php
based on the current site handle or URL so I can preview the right site page entry I'm currently editing?

Does someone had a similar situation. How did you approached and solved this? What
part am I missing?

What would be the recommended way?


Any guidance, suggestions, or pointers to th relevant craft docs would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Do you actually have a different structure for both pages? You can use a different URL template for each site and then just use {url} for the preview targets, this will show the correct URL for the current site. URL templates are also relative to the current site's base URL, so if you use something like {slug} for the URI template, it will work for both sites.
